# Pydev missing library code completion

Tags: autocomplete, pygame, pydev, code-completion

I wanted to take a look at python/pygame today, and downloaded pydev as my IDE.
Pretty satisfied overall, but it seems to be missing autocompletion for the pygame classes.

On the "screen" variable it only lists all the "**x**" functions, which I guess are the default class object functions. 
The pydev folder is added to the PYTHONPATH.

```
import os, sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

class Main:

    background_colour = (255,0,255)

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init();
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500));
        self.screen.fill(self.background_colour);
        pygame.display.flip();

        running = True
        while running:

            self.update();

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    running = False


    def update(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

The code works flawlessy, but ecspecially for a pygame/python noob like myself it is unbearable without any code completion.

Comment: I have just added "pygame" to the Forced Builtins, but it didn't make any difference

Comment: Did you enable `Use Code Completion?` within `Window > Preferences > Pydev > Editor > Code Completion`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that pydev does not know which type `self.screen` is of.

One workaround is using a local variable and `assert isinstance(...)` to help pydev.

[image]

Comment: That is pretty damn ugly, but I guess it works.
I was hoping the Forced Builtins would somehow compile the file during editing, so it knew the type. but oh well.
Is this some sort of "hacky" method, or is this the solely what assert is meant for?

Comment: It's quite hacky, yes. Code completion is just very hard for dynamic languages like python, since everything can change during runtime, entire new types could be created, method could be changed, modules dynamically imported etc etc. But pygame isn't to complicated, and I generally tend to always have the [documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/) at hand anyway.